# Jackson de-serialization doesn't work when both polymorphic types and builders are used

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

The given test fails, but I think it shouldn't.

When the data objects are converted to regular non-builder classes, the test passes (source: https://pastebin.com/pBkTb6HW).

To make the test pass with builder objects, one has to add the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation on the `Animal` interface. This means that the `Zoo` cannot be fully generic, but needs a common supertype for all animals.

It seems like this difference shouldn't exist?

Jackson version: 2.10

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `JacksonTest$Animal` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (String)"{"animals":[{"@type":"Dog","name":"doggo"},{"@type":"Cat","name":"cat"}]}"; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: JacksonTest$Zoo$Builder["animals"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Full test case:

```
public class JacksonTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        m.findAndRegisterModules();

        List<Animal> animals = List.of(
            Dog.builder().name("doggo").build(),
            Cat.builder().name("cat").build()
        );
        Zoo z = Zoo.builder().animals(animals).build();

        String json = m.writeValueAsString(z);
        Zoo deser = m.readValue(json, Zoo.class);
        assertThat(z).isEqualTo(deser);
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Zoo.Builder.class)
    static class Zoo {
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
        List<Animal> animals;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {}
    }

    interface Animal {
        String getName();
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Dog.Builder.class)
    static class Dog implements Animal {
        String name;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {}
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Cat.Builder.class)
    static class Cat implements Animal {
        String name;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we want to avoid adding to the `Animals` interface we can solve this by adding an interface, `ZooBuilder`, we then add the `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)` annotation to the `animals` mutator method and have `Zoo.Builder` implement `ZooBuilder`.

Versions:

- AdoptOpenJDK 14
- Eclipse: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
- junit: 5.6.2
- log4j2: 2.13.3
- jackson: 2.11.0
- lombok: 1.18.12

```java
package io.jeffmaxwell.stackoverflow;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
public class Q62193465 {

    static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @BeforeAll
    static void findAndRegistrerModules() {
        OBJECT_MAPPER.findAndRegisterModules();
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {

        List<Animal> animals = List.of(Dog.builder()
                .name("doggo")
                .build(),
                Cat.builder()
                .name("cat")
                .build());

        var zoo = Zoo.builder()
                .animals(animals)
                .build();

        var zooAsJsonString = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(zoo);
        LOGGER.info("zooAsJsonString {}", zooAsJsonString);
        var zooFromJsonString = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(zooAsJsonString, Zoo.class);

        assertEquals(zoo, zooFromJsonString);
    }

    //Added
    interface ZooBuilder {

        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
        Zoo.Builder animals(final List<Animal> animals);
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Zoo.Builder.class)
    public static class Zoo {
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
        List<Animal> animals;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder implements ZooBuilder {

        }
    }
    interface Animal {
        String getName();
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")

    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Dog.Builder.class)
    static class Dog implements Animal {

        String name;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
        }
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Cat.Builder.class)
    static class Cat implements Animal {

        String name;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
        }
    }
}
```

***Alternative Solution***

This avoids the interface but is more risky as it interacts with more of the Lombok generated code.

```java
package io.jeffmaxwell.stackoverflow;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
public class Q62193465 {

    static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @BeforeAll
    static void findAndRegistrerModules() {
        OBJECT_MAPPER.findAndRegisterModules();
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {

        List<Animal> animals = List.of(Dog.builder()
                .name("doggo")
                .build(),
                Cat.builder()
                .name("cat")
                .build());

        var zoo = Zoo.builder()
                .animals(animals)
                .build();

        var zooAsJsonString = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(zoo);
        LOGGER.info("zooAsJsonString {}", zooAsJsonString);
        var zooFromJsonString = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(zooAsJsonString, Zoo.class);

        assertEquals(zoo, zooFromJsonString);
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Zoo.Builder.class)
    public static class Zoo {
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
        List<Animal> animals;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {

            @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
            public Builder animals(List<Animal> animals) {
                this.animals = animals;
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
    interface Animal {
        String getName();
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")

    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Dog.Builder.class)
    static class Dog implements Animal {

        String name;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
        }
    }

    @Value
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Cat.Builder.class)
    static class Cat implements Animal {

        String name;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the wrong builder annotations, I fixed them in the question. I know that adding the `@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS)` annotation to the `Animal` interface fixes the test, that was my point though! I linked a version of this without Lombok builders in the question, and there the annotation on the `Animal` interface is not required, the one on the list suffices, as it should be IMO. This difference betweenLombok builder and non-builder behaviour is whats the problem, and I suspect it might be a bug.

Comment: Updated answer to avoid modding the `Animal` interface.

Comment: Nice, you've cracked it!